# Custom JTabbedPane LaF not showing text

Tags: java, swing, text, printing, jtabbedpane

I created a custom LaF for my JTabbedPane, the only problem is that it only renders the tab, not the text, please help, I have tried everything!

```
package com.jama.lyricist.ui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;

public class AdvancedTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI{

    @Override
    protected void paintTab(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Rectangle[] rects, int        tabIndex, Rectangle iconRect, Rectangle textRect) {
        Color savedColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(new Color(238,238,238));
        g.fillRect(rects[tabIndex].x, rects[tabIndex].y, 
               rects[tabIndex].width, rects[tabIndex].height);
        g.setColor(new Color(153, 153, 153));
        g.drawRect(rects[tabIndex].x, rects[tabIndex].y, 
               rects[tabIndex].width, rects[tabIndex].height);
        g.setColor(new Color(102,102,102));
        g.setColor(savedColor);
    }


    private final Insets borderInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    @Override
    protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
    }
    @Override
    protected Insets getContentBorderInsets(int tabPlacement) {
        return borderInsets;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintContentBorderTopEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,
                           int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.paintContentBorderTopEdge(g, tabPlacement, -1, x, y, w, h);
    }
```

}

It outputs this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djOVA.png)

Comment: Where do you draw the tab title? I think you need to throw in a `paintText` somewhere in your `paintTab` method, as shown [here](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java.htm#576)

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the paintTab() method, you're preventing the title from being painted by the base class.

You have one of two options:

1. Override paintTabBackground() and paintTabBorder() instead of overriding the paintTab() method, letting the base class paint the title
2. Paint the title yourself in your paintTab() method

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now!